# How to solve a maze in Python?

Tags: python, function, solver, maze

I am trying to write a code that solves a basic maze made up of a list of lists with '#' symbolizing walls, '.' are free spaces, S is the start and E is the end. My algorithm consists of first checking to see if the space to the right is free, if not it then checks the space up, then down, and finally to the left. I also realize that this creates a problem if there is a dead end but I'll worry about that later. So far I have code that prints the list and finds the index value of the start point which is (2,0). Basically what I am trying to do is take that starting value as the argument for my def solve function and then loop over my algorithm while marking visited positions as 'x'... if that makes any sense. What I need help with now is getting the code to loop over my algorithm so that the position is updated with each if statement. My current code only replaces 'S' with an 'x'.

```
maze = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
        ['#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'],
        ['S', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'], 
        ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', 'E'],
        ['#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#'],
        ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]

def main():

    print_maze()
    start()
    solve(start())
    print_maze()

def print_maze():

    for r in range(0,len(maze)):
        for c in range(0,len(maze)):
            print(maze[r][c], end='')
        print('')

def start():

    find_value = 'S'
        for r in range(0,len(maze)):
            for c in range (0,len(maze)):
                if find_value in maze[r][c]:
                    return(r,c)
                    break

def solve(position):
    r = position[0]
    c = position[1]

    if maze[r+1][c] == '.':  
        maze[r][c] = 'x'
        return (r+1,c)
    elif maze[r][c+1] == '.':  
        maze[r][c] = 'x'
        return (r,c+1)     
    elif maze[r][c-1] == '.':  
        maze[r][c] = 'x'
        return (r,c-1)
    elif maze[r-1][c] == '.':  
        maze[r][c] = 'x'
        return (r-1,c)
    else:
        print('Route Error')


main()
```

Comment: Why don't you paste your maze instead of showing us a snapshot?

Comment: What are you wanting `r` to be in `solve`? You haven't defined `r` in that function. You may need to review how variable scope works. `r` doesn't exist in the function just because it was defined in another function.

Comment: You asked the exact same question 2 hours ago! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009216/how-to-solve-a-basic-maze-using-functions-in-python)

Comment: Now you have modified it, you should been able to get rid of that exception.

Comment: ... and removing almost all content from the original post, that has got two answers, is considered vandalizing on SO, so please don't do that - I rolled it back to its previous version. If the answers you got didn't completely answer your question, comment on the answers if you need clarification, edit your original post, or ask a different question.

Comment: I had missed the addition of two lines in the code. Apart from that, nothing changed, neither in the code nor in the text of your question, and you supposedly still get the same error message. Your original question would get more attention if you included the exact, complete error traceback, and if you made it a [mcve]. You should definitely include your maze definition as **code** in the question itself, we don't want to re-type it to test your code. Just paste it and format it as code, as you did for the rest of your code.

Comment: I edited it so now I think it should be more clear. Lmk if this is okay or if I need to change more

Comment: Your question is still too broad for SO as it is, as answering it would pretty much mean writing the code for you at this point. As it seems to be homework, you should first try to apply what you recently learned that could apply here. Among the possible ways to solve this, maybe recursion, or depth-first/breadth-first search rings some bell?

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'r' is out of scope of the function that is throwing that exception (the function solve()).

You can change `def solve(position)` by `def solve(r, c)`.

Comment: ok so now that I did fixed that how do I get the program to loop over my if statements and update the position. My current program is only replacing 'S' with 'x'?

Comment: Now, you can check out http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html and https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html